# PHP Warning: session_start(): read failed: Input/output error (5) in /srv/data/web/vhosts

Tags: php, session

on my webserver, in the www-error.log of PHP, I see some errors :

> "PHP Warning:  session_start(): read failed: Input/output error (5) in
>   /srv/data/web/vhosts..."

It isn't the same file for each errors. And there are few errors each day.

There are no problem of rights. No disk problem.

I have no ideas. :(

Comment: maybe you've run out of space in the tmp folder ... it is a server problem .. so check your hdd's freespace etc

Comment: can you check preview on other browser ?

Comment: Please, check your system log.

Comment: I have no access to systemlog. It is a "mutual hosting". I have done a ticket for the assistance. And the assistance say me they are no disk problem.

The sessions_start() work well 99% of the time. So I think it is not a problem of rights.